# Discord API: Как упомянуть роль в Embed?

Tags: api, discord

Пишу в эмбеде <@id-роли> но выходит это
[image: Выход]

Answer (score 0):

```
<@&id-role> Как же я сам до этого не додумался...
```

Answer (score 0):

2022... ухх...
Вот, да. Написано на Disnake, пойдет 100% на Discord.Py.
я нашел этот вопрос в вкладке текущие.

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def hichat(inter):
    role = inter.guild.get_role(1184492430813298710)

    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title = "hichat",
        description=f"{role.mention} hi chat"
    )

    await inter.send(embed=embed)
```